# Firebase Hosting gray screen at startup

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I've deploy mi app into Firebase Hosting service, but when I see the URL, a gray screen apear for some seconds. I experience most on Safari than Chrome. Is there a misconfiguration or something related? Thanks in advance.

[image: gray screen]

Comment: Without seeing the [minimum code that reproduces this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it'll be hard for anyone to help.

Comment: its just a ionic3/angular4 code inside. It can be a simple html. The thing here is that after "firebase deploy" every time I see the URL generated by Firebase appear this.

Answer (score 0):

I've not experienced this personally but you may try adding ng-cloak to your HTML, which may help alleviate the flickering of content coming into view until the document and all necessary scripts have fully loaded.